# When/How does jdbc percistency enities get created

Tags: java, jdbc, persistence, persistence-unit

### **Question :**

When and how do the JDBC tables get created ?
Cause the wierd thing is that i can't find any User tabel.
I find it wierd that there is a tabel for the many-on-many relationship between User and Dish yet there is no User tabel to store the name and password of this user.

### **Structure:**

- User :

  - `String name`
  - `String password`
  - `List<Dish> shoppingList`
- Ingrediënt :

  - `String name`
- IngredientQuantity :

  - `Ingredient ingredient`
  - `Quantity quantity`
- Quantity :

  - `int quantity`
  - `String unit`
- Dish :

  - `String name`
  - `int people`
  - `Collection<IngredientQuantity> ingredients`

### **JDBC:**

[image: JDBC]

### **Persistence Unit:**

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ShoppingCalendarPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>domain.Dish</class>
    <class>domain.Ingredient</class>
    <class>domain.User</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ShoppingCalendarDB"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="app"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="app"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Maybe schema was created during early application deploys and is inconsistent with current entities? Maybe you better drop tables, use javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source and inspect sql-script?

Comment: no,I deleted the tabels and re-ran the code. Still the same.

Comment: What's the configured table name of the User entity? User is a reserved SQL keyword. Make sure you use something other than 'USER' as the table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like **JB Nizet** said, table name "user" is reserved.